# How to update time for each item

Tags: javascript, react-native, momentjs

[image]

Can someone help me how to update the log time for each item that I enter in the different time periods? Thanks, ^^. I'm using Moment.js

```
<View style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, {}]}>
  <Animated.View
  style={{
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 50,
    padding: theme.spacing.l,
  }}
  >
  {/* revenues and expenditures will appear */}
  <Animated.Text>{item.title}</Animated.Text> 
  <Text color="silver1">
    {/* time */}
    {moment().format(' Do , h:mm:ss a')}
  </Text>
  <Animated.Text
    style={{
      opacity: hidePrice,
      color: item.price > 0 ? '#009BFC' : '#FF4500',
    }}
  >
    {item.price > 0
      ? `$${item.price}`
      : `- $${Math.abs(item.price)}`}
   </Animated.Text>
 </Animated.View>
</View>
```

Comment: do you want to take current date, when user add items..?

Comment: yes this is what i want

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`moment().format('hh:mm:ss a')`

It will give you the current time save this to a variable and display

Result will be look like this: `06:19:18 pm`